# How to test asynchronous method

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I need to asynchronously fetch some data from DB, and then synchronously update currently cached data, with the one that was fetched.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
@Asynchronous
public void fetchData() {
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        //Do some logic to fetch data
        return fetchedData;
    }).thenAccept(fetchedData -> updateCache(fetchedData));
}
```

My problem is that when I call this method in my tests, it instantly goes to `thenAccept` but `fetchedData` is empty. I've tried to change my method, and return `CompletableFuture<List<Data>>`, and call `fetchData().join()` in tests. It worked fine, but first - my app wouldn't build, since `@Asynchronous` need to return `Future` or `void`, and I don't think changing method just to test it is a good idea. 
I've heard about Await library, but can not use it in current project.

I'am also not sure, if `@Asynchronous` is needed in my case? If I'm not mistaken, `CompletableFuture` should run in own thread by default?

Comment: There is no need to use `@Asynchronous` and `CompletableFuture` it makes little sense. `thenAccept` is only executed after `fetchedData` is returned if it's empty you have some other problem.

Comment: If `fetchedData` is empty in the `thenAccept()`, it means the "_Do some logic to fetch data_" returned it empty. Could you provide a [mcve] to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Jacek, I think @Asynchronous annotation is not required. You can use the pure form of completable future. I provide below the sample code based upon the code you have provided.

```
public String getInfoFromDB() {
    try {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Data from DB";
  }

  public void updateCache(String dataFromDB) {
    System.out.println("Data from D : " + dataFromDB);
    System.out.println("Doing some operations with data from DB");
  }

  public void fetchData() {
    CompletableFuture cf =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getInfoFromDB())
            .thenAccept(dataFromDB -> updateCache(dataFromDB));
    cf.join();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this useful library: [awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/)